# Am I correctly understanding TLS 1.2 PRF (Pseudorandom Function)?

Tags: tls

According to **RFC 5246** [Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-5)

```
PRF(secret, label, seed) = P_<hash>(secret, label + seed)
```

and

```
P_hash(secret, seed) = HMAC_hash(secret, A(1) + seed) +
                       HMAC_hash(secret, A(2) + seed) +
A(0) = seed
A(i) = HMAC_hash(secret, A(i-1))
```

According to my understanding first iteration of `P_hash` is

```
P_hash(secret, seed) = HMAC_hash(secret, A(0) + seed) and A(0) = seed
```

So,

```
P_hash(secret, seed) = HMAC_hash(secret, seed + seed)
```

Is it correct? Or is the first iteration rather

```
P_hash(secret, label) = HMAC_hash(secret, A(1) + Seed)
```

and

```
A(1) = HMAC_hash(secret, A(0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply by substituting `A(0)` in `A(1)`, and then `A(1)` in `P_hash`, one obtains your second suggestion. I don't understand how you came up with the first one?